# Command to list all the PIDs of all the offspring of a given process

Tags: linux, process

Is that possible to use `ps` or `pgrep` or other standard command to get all the PIDs of the currently running offspring processes of a given PID, under any Linux distrubution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pstree` command:

```
pstree -a "$PID"
```

Comment: This lists the whole process tree. I want to list only the direct and indirect children of a given process. And preferably, only PIDs, not a tree.

Comment: @JackLei Then you should have stated this in the question. Isn't it?

Comment: @JackLei You replaced `$PID` by a PID when testing my command?

Answer (score 0):

One liner for ppid = 12345:

```
/bin/ps -e -o pid,ppid | awk -v myppid=12345 '{if ($2 == myppid) { print $1; }}'
```

Or a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <ppid>" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
myppid="$1"
exec /bin/ps -e -o pid,ppid | awk -v myppid="$myppid" '{if ($2 == myppid) { print $1; }}'
```